# Simple Xtext editor for a part of a complex grammar

Tags: eclipse, grammar, dsl, xtext

I have a complex Xtext grammar, lets say a simplified version looks like this:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

ComplexGrammar:
    'Define Complex Grammar'
    (
        'Define Some Value {' someValues+=SomeValue+ '}'
        & 'Define Parts {' requiredParts+=RequiredPart+ '}'
        & 'Define FeatureX {' xfeatures+=FeatureX+ '}'
        & 'Define FeatureY {' yfeatures+=FeatureY+ '}'
    )
    'End'
;

RequiredPart:
    'Part' name=ID ';'
;

FeatureX:
    // I need this part of the grammar in a single editor.
    // It should support the Xtext validation to show errors.
    // The editor should only use FeatureX instead of the whole grammar.
    // But it also needs RequiredPart which is necessary for the complex grammar, too.
    'Here it requires' requiredPart = [RequiredPart]
;

FeatureY:
    // The same like FeatureX, but for FeatureY
    'Requires' requires = [RequiredPart] 'for FeatureY, too!'
;

SomeValue:
    // This part is not required by FeatureX or FeatureY
    // But it is required for the ComplexGrammar
    'Unimportant' name=ID 'Value' value=Double ';'
;

Double returns ecore::EDouble:
    '-'? INT? '.' INT
;
```

Now I like to integrate an editor into an eclipse FormPage.
I don't need an editor to edit the whole grammar, because it would be to complex for the user.

**What I need** is an editor for "FeatureX" and "FeatureY". Both should be separated editors and the Xtext validation in the editor for "FeatureX" should just check for errors of the grammar part "FeatureX". In other words: I need an editor for a part of a grammar, which only checks for errors of the given grammar part and it should support the simple auto-completion.

I have the **idea** to use something like a dummy of my "ComplexGrammar" to ensure the rest of the grammar is not violated, but currently I have no idea how I could open my editor using the dummy-resource and just show the editor for "FeatureX".

Hope you can give me some ideas or examples.
Thanks in advance.

Michael

**[EDIT]** I've changed the grammar above a little bit, because the example did not show one required feature: My "ComplexGrammar" defines "RequiredPart" which is also required by "FeatureX" and "FeatureY".

First of all a full example of the "ComplexGrammar" grammar:

```
Define Complex Grammar
    Define Parts {
        Part GlobalPartA ;
        Part GlobalPartB ;
    }

    Define FeatureX {
        Here it requires GlobalPartA  
    }

    Define FeatureY {
        Requires GlobalPartA for FeatureY, too!

        Requires GlobalPartB for FeatureY, too!
    }

    Define Some Value {
        Unimportant ObjName Value 1.0 ;
    }

End
```

But my editor should just work for a part of this grammar, e.g. "FeatureY":

```
Define FeatureY {
    Requires GlobalPartA for FeatureY, too!

    Requires GlobalPartB for FeatureY, too!
}
```

If I separate my grammar (like Bananeweizen said), how could I define "RequiredPart" ? Do I define this in a separated grammar too - and then I import the grammar in both grammars? Are there any other ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If that small part of the grammar is self-contained, then you can move it into its own separate grammar definition and have your complex grammar import it (just like you import the ecore definition).

The important part in separating the complex and the simplified grammar is that the complex grammar rules are allowed to refer to types and rules in the simplified grammar, but not the other way around.

And to make that all work in practice, some tweaking of the MWE workflow is necessary. Here I cannot really refer to specific instructions, it might be [this change](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/239664/).

Comment: I like your idea, but I'm not sure if I can use it for my example. I've edited my question above. Now you see that it's more complex. Do you think it would still work? Looks like I would have to create several sub-grammars to build my "ComplexGrammar". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for this extra post, but I could not edit my comment:
Imagine that I define the "RequiredPart" --> "GlobalPartA" in the complex grammar. How could I access this when separating my grammar for "FeatureY" in a separated editor? That's why I thought I could use something like the whole grammar in the background, but display an editor for "FeatureY" only - if it's possible. Then it would have the defined required parts in the background..

Comment: I have no idea, if it is possible to force an xtext editor to only edit on a sub rule and not the root rule. If you want to edit that FeatureY, you need a cross reference to a GlobalPart, but you could not create it in your restricted editor. I have no idea how one could create an instance "in the background". Seems like you should ask your question in the xtext Eclipse forum or mailing list to get an expert for that.